# Check two arrays not empty and not undefined

Tags: typescript

Suppose `arr1` is of type `number[] | undefined`. Normally, to exclude either emptyness and undefined I simply do:

```
if (arr1)
  // Here arr1 has at least one element
```

However, suppose that there is also `arr2` of type `number[] | undefined`. I would like to check both for not empty and not undefined (and also make sure that ts doesn't complain). However this behaves wierdly:

```
if (arr1 && arr2)
  // ???
```

It looks like `arr1 && arr2` is not doing a boolean AND but instead is doing a kind of intersection between the two arrays.

How could I rewrite this simple if condition to achieve what I need?

Comment: `Here arr1 has at least one element` No, it would enter there only if there is an array, no matter what it contains (including empty). You should explicitly check the `length` if you want to ensure there is at least one element: `if (arr1 && arr1.length > 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (arr1?.length && arr2?.length) {
    // both arr1 and arr2 contain at least one element
}
```

`arr1?.length` returns the length of the array or `null` if `arr1` is null.

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

```
if (arr1)
```

Only checks if the array is defined (as `!![]` returns `true`, unlike `!!''` which returns `false`)

Therefore `arr1 && arr2` will return true when both array are defined, empty or not.

What you want is following :

```
arr1 && arr1.length && arr2 && arr2.length
```

Answer (score 0):

A user-defined type guard would work:

```
function isNotEmptyOrUndefined(a: number[] | undefined): a is [number, ...number[]] {
    return Boolean(a && a.length);
}

if (isNotEmptyOrUndefined(arr1) && isNotEmptyOrUndefined(arr2)) {
    // ...
}
```

[docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Comment: Unfortunately won't compile: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: Peculiar but understandable in the way TypeScript thinks that. It should be resolvable by coercing the expression into a boolean with `!!(...)` or `Boolean(...)`.